How to sign Excel file programmatically in c# application
I have some long-existing code that uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application to manipulate Excel files, and then serves those files to client browsers in response to HTTP requests.  This software has worked for over a decade.  Critically, we have to deliver the files with macros.  We are able to sign the macros, so that part works fine.  However, with the (very appropriate) tightening of security policies by default by Microsoft, these macros are typically untrusted and disabled on the receiving client machines unless some complex security policies are adjusted (which my customers do not really want to do) or unless the user manually unblocks the download file before opening (which is just horribly ugly).
I believe that if I could sign the Excel file and serve it signed (not just the macro, mind you, but the entire file) I might be able to allow users to open the files by just responding to a warning, which would be acceptable.
However, I am having trouble understanding either through interop or through the CryptoAPI library how to sign the file.  I just need to sign programmatically so that it is signed the way it would be signed if you interactively in Excel go to File->Info->Project Workbook->sign .
I have looked for tutorials or examples of how to do this, which seems like it would be of fairly general interest, but I have come up dry.  Any help here from StackOverflowers?
To be clear, I am aware of the method Workbook.Signatures.AddNonVisibleSignature() (documented here), but that method takes an object that represents the ID of the signature provider (not explained) and furthermore the documentation suggests that "To provide an entry point to trigger this method, you need to create a user interface with the signature provider add-in. This entry point is typically provided to the user as a menu option."  My code is unattended, so there can be no mechanism to ask the user for input about the signature.  I need to interface programmatically with the actual certificate in my certificate store.

not sure if it helps in this case, but often what you can do to find how to do something with interop is to record a macro within Excel, perform the operation manually, stop/save the macro, and then review the generated code to see what it did.

Thanks @DaveCousineau - great idea - I did what you suggested.  But the macro that is recorded shows the following, which looks suspiciously not helpful!  Although helpful because I found the correct method, so that part is good....
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Signatures.AddNonVisibleSignature _
        "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
End Sub```

I don't know exactly how to help your situation, so I decided to offer some sites you can use to find your solution!

https://docs.groupdocs.com/signature/net/how-to-sign-excel-macros-using-csharp/  ... Looking at your comments, I realized that macros should be useful for you
https://blog.aspose.cloud/cells/sign-excel-using-csharp/ ... This one doesn't include macros but I still put it in in the case it helps!
https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/excel/blog/using-ironxl/csharp-open-excel-file-programmatically/ ... This one is pretty long and there's even a support team to help answer your question!

Talking about support team, a good place to look would be in other community support platforms, similiar to stack overflow. These could include public discord servers, microsoft support, e.t.c. This would be so you could also get knowledge from other areas, similiar to that of stack overflow!

Thanks so much @Coder_SPS .  These are all 3rd-party options, which aren't out of the question, but I would love to learn how to do this myself with standard Microsoft code.  If I do have to go 3rd party, these are not bad options.  The first bullet looks the most promising because it seems to me as if the 2nd and 3rd bullet both require the file to be uploaded to their servers, and our Excel files that need to be signed have sensitive customer data, so probably we can't use that.  But I'm grateful for the suggestions.

What exactly do you mean when you're saying  "I believe that if I could sign the Excel file and serve it signed', specifically the sign part. Do you mean like signature or something else?  Edit - Nevermind, it is signature

This doesn't answer the question asked. This is just links to 3rd party solutions, and answers that just contain links off-site are not helpful.
